# Remove babel from production build to reduce payload size

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Can anyone help with this question?

Does removing `babel` in production build reduce payload size?

**NB**: I only want to support modern browsers.

Comment: what do you mean with removing `babel` in production

Comment: babel is something that is not included in the production build, its used to transpile and create a browser understandable build

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Oh I see. What causes an increase in the size of the production build?  I tried removing the devTool, and I found out that the size was 50% reduced.

Comment: Also, is it compulsory to have the devTool option in the webpack config for production?

Comment: @EliasGhali, I meant removing the babel loader from webpack in production.

Comment: There are a number of ways to minify and optimise on the production build with webpack. You could search on those lines

Comment: as @ShubhamKhatri implied, babel is not included in the production, thus my question

Comment: may be your are referring to `babel-polyfill` ?. And **Yes**, removing some javascript code that goes into the bundled js does reduces the payload.

Answer (score 1):

`babel` is just a library that adds some code to yours so that the browser can understand some of the syntax that is not natively understood by the browser.

Yes, this adds to the bundle size. But if you didn't want to use `babel`, you couldn't do most of the cool stuff [here](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#readme)

If you were to remove `babel-loader` in the webpack config but still continued to use `es6` syntax, then the final distribution asset may not be understood by the browser (you'll get SyntaxErrors in the browser at runtime)